# SQL Data: HTML Table display of column data containing multiple rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-table

I'm not even sure how to ask the question properly, otherwise I probably would have found an answer. So, I will try to explain as best I can.

I'm working with a script called SLDB (I did not write these scripts), and as it stands, the scripts functions as advertised. The data that I store, I wish to call back into a website table (not what the scripts were designed to do).

Currently, the way SLDB is set up, it stores fields in this fashion:

```
    ID     Field    Value
    001     name    name1      
    001     size    size1   
    002     name    name2       
    002     size    size2      
    003     name    name3
    003     size    size3
```

In the main script that passes the variables to the database.php script, it passes name and size as 'fields' and then each of their values as 'values'.

What I would like to display on the webpage is:

```
    ID      Name    Size    
    001     name1   size1       
    002     name2   size2            
    003     name3   size3
```

In fact, I'd much rather rewrite the original script and database.php script to create and update the table in this fashion, but before I get into that, I would much rather find a way to accomplish my task without rewriting, if possible.

I am not proficient enough with mySQL to understand how to get the fields (Field, Value) with multiple variables to display separately in a single row. Currently, this is how it prints out:

http://wickednight.net/contests/photo-december/results.php

This is the simple php script I've written to display the table in html:

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","***","***","***");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM sldb_data");

    echo "<table border='1' class='db-table' align='center'>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['field'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['value'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

I realize, as written, this script is doing exactly as it's being asked to do. What I need to accomplish, however is obvious, I think. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT t1.uuid, t1.value AS name, t2.value AS size FROM sldb_data t1, sldb_data t2
WHERE t1.uuid = t2.uuid AND t1.field = "name" AND t2.field = "size"
```

Short explanation:

You can give a different name to a table in a query. This is nice when your tables have long or meaningless names. This is done in the FROM part. "sldb_data t1" gives the name "t1" to the table "sldb_data".

As we want to fetch two different rows from the same table we have to use the same table twice but we must give it two different names otherwise mysql is not knowing what exactly you want. You can think of it as if you had two identical tables.

Now we look for a row in t1 where field="name", in t2 where field="size" but only match those together with same uuid.

After the SELECT we just list the fields we want in our result. And again we give a name to the fields. But with fields you have to use the "as".

Comment: I agree with you completely. For this project I'm working on, I just wanted to get through this with the simplest solution, but I already realize for other applications, I am going to have to fumble my way through rewriting both scripts involved in creating the database and tables. I will attempt your solution and report back.  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Additional explanation please. Or maybe a link to point me to where I can learn what your select function is doing? My database is wreckers_photodec. The table is sldb_data. In sldb_data it contains the columns id (the auto incremented id), uuid (which I posted above as id for simplicity), field, value. The field column contains the rows name, size and the value column contains the variables of each of those. I can tell you had a good grasp of what I was asking, it's my own limited knowledge that prevents me from understanding your select query... where t1, t2, and test come from.

Comment: Great explanation, Thank you. And works exactly as you intended, when querying in phpmyadmin. Now, I just need to get it to display as an html table showing each name and size per row. I had an error at first, but the problem was my fault. The link I posted above shows the results of your solution. Thank you, Alva. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but I can say that its not good idea to storing form field name and their each value. May be you already know we use name and value for inserting purpose with using post/get method.

Your sldb_data table may have

```
id(PK) name( varchar) size(int)
```

in three columns and then change your query like

```
SELECT name,size FROM sldb_data
```

and your code should

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['size'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. your response is how I would have done it, if I had written the scripts. But, of course, I only realized what it was doing after I set it all up and ran the scripts. If I have to muddle my way through rewriting the scripts, that's how I would set it up. But, as I said, before I got into that, I wanted to see if there was a simple solution to finishing this project, then I would worry about rewriting for future applications. Your response did confirm that my initial thoughts of 'how it should have worked' were correct, so thank you for that.

Comment: please learn basic first. we cant help you if you haven't specific problem. See [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: I've already stated my specific problem in the post above. What you've written is how it "should have been", not a solution to the current problem. I am waiting for AlvaHenrik to respond, as that solution seems to be what I need.